# SUMIF - range and value on different rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to write a SUMIF formula based on checking to see if a specific value is present on the row above but spread across different rows as in the image below.
Any help appreciated

[image: explanation images]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use something like `=sumif(B3:F3,H2,B4:F4)`

`=sumif(range of group1 headings,cell to the left of total hours,range of group1 numbers)`

your question is not too clear but you may be trying to sum all the groups together at once which you can't do with a single sumif but you can add 3 sumif funtions together in the same formula.

`=sumif(B3:F3,H2,B4:F4)+sumif(B6:F6,H2,B6:F6)+sumif(B9:F9,H2,B9:F9)`